# Will ROW_NUMBER() always order the outer result?

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm using a CTE to rank book authors based on their sales rank. I understand that `ROW_NUMBER()` can take in an `ORDER BY` to determine the returned row number based on it.

My query looks like this:

```
WITH cte (idWork, author, rn)
AS
(
    SELECT
        idWork,
        authorName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idWork ORDER BY authorSalesRank)
    FROM dbo.Works_Authors_Works
    INNER JOIN Authors ON Authors.idAuthor = Works_Authors_Works.idAuthor
)
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM cte
```

I noticed that the the results look like this, which is as expected:

```
+---------+----------------+------+
| idWork  | author         | rn   |
+---------+----------------+------+
| 1       | test1          | 1    |
| 1       | test2          | 2    |
| 1       | test3          | 3    |
| 2       | beep1          | 1    |
| 2       | beep2          | 2    |
| 3       | nobody         | 1    |
+---------+----------------+------+
```

I have two questions with this CTE:

- Will the results always be sorted on the `ROW_NUMBER` field `rn`? Like how the results are grouped on `idWork` then sorted on `rn`? For example, when `idWork` is 1, the rows are sorted on `rn` from 1, 2, then 3. Is this a coincidence or will it always be like this?
- If I do a `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM cte WHERE idWork = 1`, will it always return the row where `rn` = 1?

In the execution plan, it has an input Sort on `idWork`, `authorSalesRank`. Do these imply that the outer result is sorted on this too?

[image: execution plan]
[image: execution plan - sort details]

Comment: Without an order by on the select from the CTE the results could come back in an indeterminate order.

Comment: If you have other Row_Number() over (order by author desc) then we cannot guarantee which order by precedes. In the execuation plan 'ordered' will not be true

Comment: I've attached the execution plan and it looks like it does get ordered at some point in the pipeline

Comment: That order is so row_numbers can be assigned.  However if you were to lets say, join in the select of the CTE to another table with it's data being listed first in the select, the order would likely vary than what you see now.  ORDER Is NEVER guaranteed without an ORDER By for the related select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should explicitly order it.

```
WITH cte (idWork, author, rn) AS (
    SELECT
        idWork,
        authorName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY idWork ORDER BY authorSalesRank) AS rn
    FROM dbo.Works_Authors_Works
    INNER JOIN Authors ON Authors.idAuthor = Works_Authors_Works.idAuthor
)
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM cte
order by idWork, rn
```

SQL (all databases) do not guarantee order if no order is specified, even if it *seems* like it "always works", you should not rely on that anecdotal evidence.

Comment: Excellent point: order is never guaranteed w/o order by...but it is *usually* ordered by the indexes at play, which can vary with the query plan.

Comment: @Clay yes, things can change for example when the database returns cached results, which may be cached/returned inn arbitrary order for performance